# Resolve generics with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, reflection, mono.cecil

I have a hierarchy of types of unknown depth. But at the and, this hierarchy implements `IPlugin<T>` or `IPlugin<T1, T2>` interface (from the other `.dll`). How can I resolve `<T>` or `<T1, T2>` generics from `IPlugin`? This generics position can be random on the top class.

Example:

```cs
// other .dll
interface IPlugin<T> {}
interface IPlugin<T1, T2> {}

// my code
class PluginBase<T1, T2>: IPlugin<T2, T1> {}
class AnotherClass<T1, T2, T3>: PluginBase<T3, T1> {}
class Plugin: AnotherClass<string, int, char> {}
```

From this example i expect `string` and `char` type definition.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/tomspilman/99ddac3b60f72814c6e5), but it uses the position of the arguments and there is no traversal of the hierarchy.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Your `Plugin` class inherits from `AnotherClass<string, int, char>` which inherits from `PluginBase<char, string>` which implemets `IPlugin<string, char>` (boy that's confusing - all that changing around of the order of the types).  What do you want to know?

Comment: @Flydog57 I need to know how resolve `IPlugin` generics with mono.cecil. When I load assemblies, only `Plugin` class has closed generics.

Comment: My understanding is that cecil is like reflection - it looks at assemblies and sees types.  An assembly that contains the definition of a generic type (like `AnotherClass<T1, T2, T3>`) only contains the definition in generic form (with weirdly back-quoted type parameters).  That definition has no idea how another assembly may full instantiate a type like `AnotherClass<string, int, char>`.  You can't see that in the assembly with the generic definition.  What do you mean by _"know how [to] resolve IPlugin generics"_

Comment: Yes, but we have type with closed generics, so we can traverse hierarchy and resolve `IPlugin` generics. Maybe someone knows how to make it simple in Mono.cecil.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tomspilman/99ddac3b60f72814c6e5
here is an example, but it uses the position of the arguments and there is no traversal of the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a code like this:

```cs
        public class TypeWithSelfReference
        {
            public TypeWithSelfReference(TypeDefinition type, TypeReference reference)
            {
                Type = type;
                Reference = reference;
            }

            public TypeDefinition Type { get; }

            public TypeReference Reference { get; }

            public void Deconstruct(out TypeDefinition type, out TypeReference derived)
            {
                type = Type;
                derived = Reference;
            }
        }

        public static List<TypeWithSelfReference> GetHierarchy(this TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Func<TypeDefinition, bool> breakCondition)
        {
            var hierarchy = new List<TypeWithSelfReference>();

            foreach (var definition in typeDefinition.Traverse())
            {
                hierarchy.Add(new TypeWithSelfReference(definition, null));

                if (breakCondition(definition))
                    break;
            }

            hierarchy.Reverse();

            for (var i = 0; i < hierarchy.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                hierarchy[i] = new TypeWithSelfReference(hierarchy[i].Type, hierarchy[i + 1].Type.BaseType);
            }

            return hierarchy.Take(hierarchy.Count - 1).ToList();
        }

        private static TypeReference ResolveGenericParameter(IEnumerable<TypeWithSelfReference> hierarchy, GenericParameter parameter)
        {
            foreach (var (type, reference) in hierarchy)
            {
                foreach (var genericParameter in type.GenericParameters)
                {
                    if (genericParameter != parameter)
                        continue;

                    var nextArgument = ((GenericInstanceType) reference).GenericArguments[genericParameter.Position];

                    if (!(nextArgument is GenericParameter nextParameter))
                        return nextArgument;

                    parameter = nextParameter;

                    break;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```